# Is there a term for actors rehearsing lines in a different accent?

Tags: terminology, acting

I've seen a few examples of actors rehearsing a scene, but in different accents to their own.

In *Shaun of the Dead*, Simon Pegg and Peter Serafinowicz pretend to be John Lennon and Paul McCartney.

In *Star Trek*, Chris Pine and Zachary Quinto rehearse in a German and Irish accent, respectively:

And Michael J Fox in *Back to the Future*:

I imagine it's a way to let off steam, or make a long day of filming entertaining, but is there a specific term for what's seen above?

For example, does the director say: "One more take, but this time let's do [term]", or is it more likely an idea that springs up on set?

Comment: There's absolutely zero legit use for this footage except for the Blooper Reel, so I'd imagine it's just a way to blow off steam of get the "sillies" out  of the actors.  As a result, Luciano's answer is probably most relevant to this question.

Comment: I'm sure you can find any number of blooper reel where they use silly accents. Adding the Michael J Fox one doesn't really add much to the question.  What is wrong with the current answer in your view? You might have to accept that there may not *be* a more technical term for what you are defining here.

Answer (score -1):

[From the Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impersonation), the technical term would be:

### Impersonation

> to assume or act the character of
>
> IMPERSONATE, PLAY, and ACT mean to pretend to be somebody else. IMPERSONATE is used when someone tries to look and sound like another person as much as possible.  *You're good at impersonating celebrities.*  PLAY is used when someone takes a part in a play, movie, or TV show.  *You can play the part of the spy.*  ACT may be used in situations other than performing in a drama or pretending to be a person. *Act like you're a dog.*

So the director could say "One more take, this time act as John Lennon" or "do it with a German accent". I'm not sure anyone would ask "impersonate a german", it's quite clear that *do as* means *impersonate*.

The term is more commonly used when referring to someone in the 3rd person, "he was a John Lennon impersonator".

Also from [the same dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impression):

### Impression

> an imitation or representation of salient features in an artistic or theatrical medium
> especially : an imitation in caricature of a noted personality as a form of theatrical entertainment

More sources: https://www.wikihow.com/Do-Impressions-of-Famous-People

Comment: Trying out a different accent is would not be considered equal to being another person, right?
It can be a part of impersonation.

Comment: @AnkitKante I don't understand the downvote, read my answer: "t's quite clear that _do as_ means _impersonate_." So I did say doing accents is also impersonation. It's voice impersonation.

Comment: I just shared my opinion. I did not downvote your answer.